# How to avoid error messagebox if .net is not installed on client system

Tags: .net

I have a C# application which request .net 2 on client system. I like to replace the error message box in case if .net2 is not detected with ruuning an executable program which I have a written how do not request .net2.

Edited a solution can be found at [url](http://improve.dk/blog/2007/06/10/creating-a-dotnet-bootstrapped-installer-using-nsis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be the point of hiding the error message?  Now your customer (nor you) would not have any clue at all why your program won't run.  A friendlier error message still doesn't solve the problem.  Include the .NET bootstrapper in your setup program so this just won't happen.

Comment: Hi, well I dont want to hide the error message, I want replace this function with an now function which runs an native application which automatically download and install the requeststed gears.

Comment: That's what setup.exe does when you include the .NET bootstrapper.

Comment: Hi, I dont use an setup what i have is a standalone executable file which I share with my friends. anyway I have found a solution for this problem @ http://improve.dk/blog/2007/06/10/creating-a-dotnet-bootstrapped-installer-using-nsis..... thanks to your input.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run a native app first to check if it's installed and if so you start the .Net app otherwise your other native app.